# how to remove starting div elements using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div ="fullcontainer">
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
<div id="c"></div>
<div id="d"></div>
<div id="e"></div>

</div>

$('#fullContainer').children().slice(2).remove();
```

it gives result :

```
<div ="fullcontainer">
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
</div>
```

how to get result like this?

```
<div ="fullcontainer">

<div id="d"></div>
<div id="e"></div>

</div>
```

**Second Question**
I got last and second last  div id like this :

```
$('#fullContainer div:last-child').attr('id');

$('#fullContainer div:nth-last-child(2)').attr('id');
```

How to get first and second div id ?

Comment: Why are you not just doing '$("#a").remove();' etc

Comment: `fullcontainer` is id or class, I think you missed `id` attribute of main div.

Answer (score 3):

You can use following code to remove first div:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#fullcontainer div:first-child").remove();
});
```

Checkout Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/aX83W/

Answer (score 1):

Try using [**`.eq()`**](https://api.jquery.com/eq/),

```
$('#fullContainer').children().eq(0)  //first div
$('#fullContainer').children().eq(1)  //second div
.
.
$('#fullContainer').children().eq(n)  //nth div
```

Full code for your requirement,

```
var cache = $('#fullContainer').children();
cache.first().remove();  //removing the first one
cache.eq(cache.length - 2).attr('id'); // getting the id of the second one from the last.
```

For your new edit you can try like,

```
   var cache = $('#fullContainer').children();
   cache.filter(':lt(' + (cache.length - 2) + ')').remove();
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aX83W/1/)

Answer (score 1):

To remove first

```
$('#fullContainer').children().first().remove();
```

IDs

```
$('#fullContainer div:first-child').attr('id');

$('#fullContainer div:nth-child(2)').attr('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `start` and `end` [slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) to remove first 3 elements like

```
$('#fullContainer').children().slice(0,3).remove();// remove first 3 elements
```

To get `first` and `second` element `id` try to use **[eq-selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)**,

```
$('#fullContainer div:eq(0)').attr('id');// first element id
$('#fullContainer div:eq(1)').attr('id');// second element id
```

Or you can try **[nth-child selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)**,

```
$('#fullContainer div:nth-child(1)').attr('id');// first element id
$('#fullContainer div:nth-child(2)').attr('id');// second element id
```

**Note** make sure your div-id is `fullcontainer`(you missed id from your div element) and you are using `fullContainer` in jquery, to work properly both must be same.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xQ67q/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use :first or first() or you can use even eq() operator

```
$('#fullContainer div :first').remove()
```

or

```
$('#fullContainer div').first().remove()
```

or

```
$('#fullContainer div').eq(0).remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
To remove first

$('#fullContainer').children().first().remove();
```

also

```
$('#fullContainer').children(div:nth-of-type(1)).remove();
$('#fullContainer').children(div:nth-of-type(1)).remove(); 
$('#fullContainer').children(div:nth-of-type(1)).remove();
```

and even like this to get

```
$('#fullContainer div:nth-child(1)').attr('id');
$('#fullContainer div:nth-child(2)').attr('id');
$('#fullContainer div:nth-child(n)').attr('id');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#fullContainer div').eq(0).remove();
```